# How do I monitor a deep value in object while using vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Please check this example.

https://codepen.io/suedar/pen/XGyGOj

After I click the `li`, the `div` is required to display which is not.

I know it is because [Reactivity in Depth](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55295528/edit).
I want to know how can I monitor a deep value in object while using `vuex`. Thanks for ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Deep `watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) should work on Vuex store as well.

```js
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'allCategory'
    ])
  },
  
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([
      'CHANGE_ALL_CATEGORY'
    ]),
    
    toggleTab(index, isShow) {
      // ...some action
      this.CHANGE_ALL_CATEGORY(allCategory);
    },
  },
  
  watch: {
    allCategory: {
      handler(val) {
        this.CHANGE_ALL_CATEGORY(val);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
```